# Oracle sequences - what happens if a sequence generates a number that already exists in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on fixing some tables created by another developer in the past and one of the tables did not use a sequence for its primary key - any number can be inserted into the PK field. I created a trigger for that table that would utilize an existing sequence. The issue is that the table already has some records with random values inserted into primary key field. When I created a trigger, the latest sequence value was at 101, but the table has one of the primary keys set to 151. What will happen when the sequence will generate 151 and attempt to insert it into the table? Will it simply be forced to go to 152 or will the trigger fail? What can I do to prevent the failure?

Comment: Simply select the current max value. Let the sequence start with that value + 1.

Comment: it is an existing sequence - the standard is to reuse the same sequence for a set of tables. We do not use max but must use sequence to generate PK

Comment: You can select 50 dummy rows in a query that includes `yoursequence.nextval`, to bring the current value up above 151. For larger amounts you can `alter sequence yoursequence increment by 1000000;` (or whatever value you need), fetch 1 value, then set the increment back to 1 again.

Comment: "Will it simply be forced to go to 152 or will the trigger fail? "  it will fail with a 'duplicate key' error.  There is no inherent connection between a sequence and a table.  A sequence simply provides a number, to be used however you wish. In your case your trigger gets that number then tries to use it as a PK.  If/when it fails, that's on you, not the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should create error. Your insertion will fail for sequence 151 and with next try the sequence will be 152 and that will succeed.

You can create a new sequence starting from the higher value of all the id in current table then select from that sequence.
Create sequence starting from 152 is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE New_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 152
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

And surely you can alter your sequence to restart it from 152 as @jarlh suggested.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequencename MINVALUE 152 RESTART
```

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica, isn't "_"It should create error._" an answer to the question?

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica I have elaborated my answer to that question. Thanks jarlh.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur, OP wants to use an alreadyexisting sequence. I suppose something like `ALTER SEQUENCE sequencename MINVALUE 152 RESTART` can be done. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-A6468B63-E7C9-4EF0-B048-82FE2449B26D

Comment: I though she might not want to alter an existing sequence. But definitely it's a good option. I have edited my answer with your suggestion.